# How to use a select dropdown in a virtualized list?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

Im currently developing a react app which has a virtualized list (https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) in it. The items in the list may contain a select dropdown.

**The problem now:**
The virtualized list is hiding overflow. So the last items dropdown is not displayed and you cannot scroll down to view the content of the dropdown:

[image]

================= Here is where the image ends ================

I have no idea, how I could fix this issue, without changing the virtualized list code. Anybody out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

react-virtualized can't use `overflow: visible` without breaking scroll behavior (which is pretty key to how react-virtualized works). So things like drop-downs will get clipped as you've observed.

What I typically recommend for people wanting to put things like drop-down menus inside of react-virtualized rows is to use a portal. This allows the menu content to expand outside of a single row (or even the entire `List`) without being clipped.

I've used [tajo/react-portal](https://github.com/tajo/react-portal) in the past for this.

Comment: Portals are now an integral part of React 16. See https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: react-portal uses React 16's portals API. The reason I recommended using it instead of the barebones portal API is that it manages things like positioning the "drop down" over its target button.

Comment: Didn't realise that this project had been updated to use React 16, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Has anyone used Portal with Table? Any hint will be appreciable I am stuck since two todays.